# How to hide / unhide a process in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, process

I am attempting to start an external process in a Visual C# 2010 - Windows Forms application.  The goal is to start the process as a hidden window, and unhide the window at a later time.

I've updated my progress:

```
//Initialization
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool EnableWindow(IntPtr hwnd, bool enable);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, 
int height, bool redraw);

SW_SHOW = 5;
```

The following was placed in my main function:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("process.exe");
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process p = Process.Start(info);

p.WaitForInputIdle();
IntPtr HWND = p.MainWindowHandle;

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);    

ShowWindow(HWND, SW_SHOW);
EnableWindow(HWND, true);
MoveWindow(HWND, 0, 0, 640, 480, true);
```

However, because the window was started as "hidden," `p.MainWindowHandle = 0`.  I am not able to successfully show the window.  I have also tried `HWND = p.Handle` with no success.

Is there a way to provide a new handle to my window?  This could potentially fix my problem.

References:

[MSDN ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsmobiledev/thread/12d1840d-e894-4097-ae41-46e69bb5b5c0/)

[How to Import .dll](http://en.csharp-online.net/Attributes)

Comment: Hiding a process? (dodgy) - or hiding a form?

Comment: Hiding the window of a process.  For the sake of argument, let's assume it's internet explorer: `ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("iexplore");`

Comment: CreateNoWindow only works on a console mode app.  Hidden requires a GUI app to cooperate and pay attention to the `nCmdShow` argument that Windows passes to its WinMain() function.  That is however often ignored.  Nothing you can do about it other than contacting the owner.

Comment: I've updated my progress above.  Please advise, and thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally, the process is operating properly.  Thanks to all of your help, I came up with this fix.

The p.MainWindowHandle was 0, so I had to use the user32 FindWindow() function to get the window handle.

```
//Initialization
int SW_SHOW = 5;

[DllImport("user32.dll",SetLastError=true)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool EnableWindow(IntPtr hwnd, bool enabled);
```

And in my main function:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "notepad";
info.UseShellExecute = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process p = Process.Start(info);
p.WaitForInputIdle();
IntPtr HWND = FindWindow(null, "Untitled - Notepad");

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

ShowWindow(HWND, SW_SHOW);
EnableWindow(HWND, true);
```

References:

[pinvoke.net: FindWindow()](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindow.html)

Edit:
Removed WindowShowStyle from the dllImport declaration: you can define this as an int instead. I defined an enum called WindowShowStyle to define the constants outlined in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow). It just better fits my coding patterns to have enums defined instead of using constant or hard-coded values.

Comment: Hi Matt thanks for sharing. I know this is late, but when I try this code, Visual Studio can't recognise `WindowShowStyle`. I have checked all the links you provided but can't find any mention of this type - could you please let me know where this is coming from? (I am referring to the type of the 2nd parameter in the `ShowWindow` import declaration)

Comment: So sorry for the delay in this answer! Hope you found what you needed.

Answer (score 2):

Sample code to unhide the window:

```
int hWnd;
Process[] processRunning = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process pr in processRunning)
{
    if (pr.ProcessName == "notepad")
    {
        hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try this when i get home. If it works, I'll accept it. Isn't there a find window method?

Comment: After re-reading this, I have further concerns.  There is no way to know that pr is *my* process.  For instance, what if my program opened two notepad windows?  I wonder if there is a better way to identify the window that I have opened.

Answer (score 1):

The documention details that to use `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` you must also set `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute` to false.  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle.aspx](http://bit.ly/KoEj1j)

You would have to somehow know the window handle to unhide it later.

Comment: Please provide documentation.  Testing shows that `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true` is the only way that `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`  will work.

Comment: looking up ProcessWindowStyle on MSDN was assumed; but I've added the link for you.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, for whatever reason, it does not work in my case.  As mentioned above, I tested with both `true` and `false`.  While using `false`, the window failed to hide.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem trying to maximize a Windows App (calculator) again, after minimizing it. Getting the window to the front worked (`SetForegroundWindow`), but as soon as the window was minimized, the calculator app's window handle couldn't show it anymore (`ShowWindow`).

**The problem with Windows Apps is that their actual top level windows are owned by the `ApplicationFrameHost` process.** The window that the app has is just its "canvas", hence you cannot get the real handle via `Process.MainWindowHandle`. If you are confident that you know the title of the window you are looking for, you can enumerate all of `ApplicationFrameHost`'s windows (`EnumThreadWindows`) and use `GetWindowText` to find the one that has the right title. You might also try your luck with `FindWindow`, though that didn't work for me.

I wasn't confident (different localizations!), but I also started the app myself. So I remember the list of windows in `ApplicationFrameHost` before launching the calculator app, and get it again a while later. Then I can compare them, to see which window is new. It's probably going to be that window! Not 100% safe, but seems to work so far. There are also the window titles `MSCTFIME UI` and `Default IME` multiple times (one for each real window), which I ignore.